# Proof of Implicit function theorem

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I was trying for a simple proof for implicit function theorem on two variables.I came across a book by Dipak Chatterjee.It says as follows :

$f(x,y)$ be a function of two variables and $(a,b) be a point in its domain such that

1) $f(a,b)=0$

2)$f_{x}$ and $f_{y}$ are continuous in a neighbourhood of $(a,b)$

3)$f_{y}(a,b) \neq 0$

Then there exist a rectangle $[a-h,a+h] $ X $[b-k,b+k]$ such that there exist a function $\phi :[a-h,a+h] \longrightarrow  [b-k,b+k]$  as $\phi(x)=y$ and this function $\phi$ satisfies the above properties :

i) $b=\phi(a)$

ii) $f(x,\phi(x))=0$ for every $x \in [a-h,a+h]$

iii) $\phi$ is derivable on $[a-h,a+h]$

iv) $\phi^{'}$ is continuous on $[a-h,a+h]$

This is the statement of the theorem.While in proof he starts with the assumption that $f_{y}(a,b)>0$ and takes the neighbourhood where $f_{x}$ and $f_{y}$ are continuous as $N(a,b)$.In this neighbour hood our function $f$ will be continuous..
My doubt is in next statement.He says since $f_{x}$ continuous at $(a,b)$ and $f_{y}(a,b)>0$ we can find a neighbourhood of $(a,b)$ where $f_{y} > 0 $.

I could not understand this justification ?How is it possible ? Is there any flaw in this argument..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f_y$ is continuous. Thus $\{(x,y):f_y(x,y)>0\}$ or $\{(x,y):f_y(x,y)>\frac12·f(a,b)\}$ are open sets and thus contain open balls around $(a,b)$.

Comment: okey.. now I understood .I have tried with a single variable case as follows: Let $y=f(x)$ be continuous at $a$ it means for every positive $\epsilon$ we get  a positive $\delta$ such that $x \in (a-\delta,a+\delta) \Longrightarrow f(x) \in (f(a)-\epsilon,f(a)+\epsilon)$.Since we know that $f(a)>0$ we can choose $\epsilon$ such that $ (f(a)-\epsilon,f(a)+\epsilon)$ contains only positive numbers.Corresponding delta neighbourhood is the required neighbourhood.Here in IFT we are treating two variable function as single variables by fixing one variable and changing the other.Is it Okey ?